# How can I exclude a certain wiki page from appearing in the trac search?

Tags: python, wiki, trac

We use the [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) project management software. I want to be able to prevent certain wiki pages appearing in the trac search results. For example, some developers keep timesheets in the wiki and they contain a lot of keywords but never much useful documentation.

Is there a way to configure trac to ignore a list of wiki pages?

---

For reference, this is what I currently have in the `[search]` and `[wiki]` sections of my `trac.ini`:

```
[search]
default_disabled_filters = changeset, milestone
min_query_length = 3

[wiki]
ignore_missing_pages = false
max_size = 262144
render_unsafe_content = true
split_page_names = false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that out-of-the-box, and I don't know of a plugin that allows to do that. You would have to write a small plugin that monkey-patches the method `get_search_results()` of `WikiModule` (see [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser//trunk/trac/wiki/web_ui.py?rev=10706&marks=753#L746)) and filters the results (probably by matching the URL, which would be a bit of a hack).